# Converting JPG to Bitmap with-out changing size

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap, jpeg

I save `.jpg` image in my `cache` folder. Image is 4,032x3,024 (24-bit color) that weights 3.35MB.
Now, I wanted to convert this very same `jpg` to `bitmap`.

I used code:

```
val bitmapFromJpg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(jpgFile.absolutePath)
```

But what surprised me was that it automatically changed the orignal size of the image - 1,024x768 (32-bit).

Even with

```
val opts = BitmapFactory.Options()
opts.inSampleSize = 1
val bitmapFromJpg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(jpgFile.absolutePath, opts)
```

result is the same...

Why is this happening and how to avoid it (I want to keep original size)?

Comment: try setting opts.inScaled = false

Comment: `Image size is 4,032x3,024 `. That is called resolution.

Comment: `that weights 3.35MB.` ? You mean: the file size is 3.35MB?

Comment: Your story is hard to believe. Please show code that determines the resolution of the bitmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can change `inScaled`

By default it's value is `true`, try this code

```
val opts = BitmapFactory.Options()
opts.inSampleSize = 1
opts.inScaled = false
val bitmapFromJpg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(jpgFile.absolutePath, opts)
```

I tested this my `jpg` image size(HeightXWidth) was 600X600 and after converting to `bitmap` it remain same 600X600.